# Best questions and answers from 2nd quarter of 2020

Tags: discussion, best-of

Some Stack Exchange sites, such as [Literature Stack Exchange](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-of), [Science Fiction and Fantasy Stack Exchange](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10763/89356), [Puzzling Stack Exchange](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-of) and [Spanish Language SE](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=Nominaciones+a+la+mejor+respuesta), have (or had, as the case may be) a tradition of trying to identify the best questions and answers from the last quarter. These are contributions that may be posted on a blog or a Twitter account if the site has one; otherwise they are a nice collection of the best contributions made in a community.

In addition to identifying material that can be used to promote the site elsewhere, such a list of nominations can also be used to highlight high-quality contributions that did not get a lot of votes when they were posted.

So what are the rules?

- Find **great questions with great answers** from the last quarter. There are [264 questions](https://french.stackexchange.com/search?q=created%3A2020-04..2020-06+is%3Aq) and another [460 answers](https://french.stackexchange.com/search?q=created%3A2020-04..2020-06+is%3Aa)  to choose from.
- You can nominate multiple posts per answer.
- Some sort of explanation *why* the nominated post is particularly good would be worth adding. This can give future contributors an idea of how to write up good questions or answers.

Comment: We used to do the same [in Spanish.SE](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=Nominaciones+a+la+mejor+respuesta) for a while, and even give bounties to the top 3.

Comment: @fedorqui Thanks. I have added the link. Unfortunately, I don't have the reps to liberally distribute bounties on this site ;-)

Answer (score 4):

It is always difficult to establish a restricted list of best questions and answers. Here is a small selection that reflects some of the content I liked the most this quarter.

- **["Dernier Cri"](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/41860/when-did-the-expression-dernier-cri-start-to-be-used-in-the-context-of-fashion/41861): a question about origins.**

This question, coming from a discussion on Spanish SE, asked about the origins of the expression "*dernier cri*" referring to fashion trends. This is a very personal choice, as I had a lot of fun researching old books, catching a glimpse of 17th Century France. I also love that this question originates from a discussion about another language, making a connection between several SE sites and underlining similarities between latin languages.

- **["Help me name my wine"](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/41893/please-help-me-name-my-wine/41894): a controversial question.**

This question is a perfect example of: "is this acceptable for this site?" and I like this because it doesn't leave you stone cold. One may wonder how naming a wine is related to French language, and I, myself, wasn't sure about the answer, as I initially voted to close the question and then retracted. What I like about this question is that it showed a certain enthusiasm from an American person trying to use French in a creative way, and it seemed like people had fun commenting or answering it. In general, I like questions that are open enough to leave a bit of creativity from the answerers.

- **["Subjonctif dans les phrases inversées"](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/42038/subjonctif-dans-les-phrases-invers%C3%A9es-commen%C3%A7ant-par-que/42061#42061): a very complete answer.**

Some people are just passionate about French language, and sometimes it shows. Here, *Pas un Clue* answers a question about a specific usage of the subjonctive tense, giving a lot of examples and going quite deeply into the analysis of why some sentence structures can be useful in certain contexts. It gives a lot of details while remaining relevant, and I liked reading it a lot.